# define language dynamically asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

I have a case that I have to get the language defined by admin. I know how to do language supported web sites such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163215/Dynamic-definition-of-the-list-of-available-langua

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =  
                   CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        }
```

but the consumer wants to define the language so he doesnt need me to change the source code everytime he wants to add a new language. I have been searching but reached to nothing. Could anyone give me any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own ResourceExpressionBuilder that stores key/value/language information in a database table. You can then provide interface in the administration to add languages and update values based on this database table. The expression builder will allow you to use the same syntax for localization as with the built in resource files. It is not a fast and easy solution though. It takes time to implement this.

Alternatively you can teach the customer to create resource files and deploy them on the server. This should not require compilation.

Here is an example on how to override the resource manager. You can also create your own expression http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceexpressionbuilder.aspx

Comment: It sure will take time. I was thinking to implement a solution database supported. But then the problem is app_LocalResources files. I need to get them dynamic. I mention of course about the resx files. They are xml based. Maybe I can create a new xml file and store it into the app_LocalResources file.Do you think that would work?

Comment: You will not use resource files if you use a database. In theory you could but why would you if you have a database? I am not sure what will happen if you create a resource file dynamically but I wouldn't recommend it. It may be possible though.

Comment: How will I able to apply the languages to the labels,buttons etc. then? I shouldnt do like if(lang="en-US")label1.text="English" else etc . Could you give any clue about that?

Comment: Of course not. Do you do it this way now? You should do it like this 
label1.text = this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "Hello") as string;

Comment: So it seams that I have to change the label text according to the language. I didnt want to do this beucause it is not very well programming. If I do this, I have to write a function or whatevet which changes the texts of the elements. The problem is that I will have more than 1 page in the system. Each page will have labels, buttons etc.. and so on. When the customer wants the add a new lang, will I have to store every text of the label to the database? then get them according to the page Id and change the text? this doenst seem to be the proper way. I will have user controls as well.

Comment: How do you deal with different languages now?

Comment: I staticly define the resx files for everypage. Then I use the label attribute "meta:resources". so the label gets the definiton according to the selected language which is in CurrentCultureInfo. Can I generate resx files dynamically? it contains xml so i should be able to do that. what do you think?

Comment: As I already said I am not sure what will happen if you generate resx files dynamically. It may be possible. I think you should store the resources in the database. There is nothing that prevents you from using the meta:resources attribute with custom resourcemanager that reads key/value pairs from the database instead of resx files.

Comment: you are rigth coz I can get values of the elements from the database.But this will reduce the speed of the system. Let's say that the speed is not important so much then I have to do "this.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "Hello")" for every element in the page.This %100 will work. I think I have figured a technique. I just copied pasted the resx file and change the content of it. I gave it a name WebForm1.aspx.en-US.resx. That worked. If this works then I can create a new file like this coz it contais xml. If I copy this to the app_localresources, it will work.

Comment: You can use the very same meta keys if you implement your own resource manager. Also you can get the resources from the DB once when the application starts and never again hit the DB.

Comment: That could be better than the first solution you mentioned. Thank you very much for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

You could store the language in a database table, and call it from there, and apply the value to your `language` variable.

```
cmd SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Language FROM [WebsiteLanguage]",conn);
objLanguage Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (!(objLanguage==null)){
   language = objLanguage;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
}
```

Then admin could `UPDATE` the language via a form in your admin area.

Comment: That sounds fine but how will I able to apply to the app_LocalResources file for page components? ex: "meta.resourcekey" because  there will be no added app_LocalResources file "resx".